# avoiding ambiguous SFINAE access when both base and derived class have variadic inheritance chains

Tags: templates, inheritance, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

Using SFINAE, one can access individual elements of a variadic class template. My problem occurs when a base class inherits from a variadic class template, and then a derived class inherits from the base and from the variadic class template again (with different template arguments). An ambiguity exists as to which inheritance chain should be followed. Is there a way to resolve the ambiguity?

For example:

```
// compile with flag: -std=c++11
#include <type_traits>

struct A { int x; };
struct B { int x; };
struct C { int x; };
struct D { int x; };

template <class ... Params> class Parameter { };

template <class Param, class ... Tail>
class Parameter<Param, Tail ...> : public Param, public Parameter<Tail ...>
{
  public:
    //! Get a parameter
    template <class Param2>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Param, Param2>::value, int>::type
    getParam() const
    { return Param::x; }

    //! Get a parameter. Delegate false template matches down the Tail... inheritance line (see SFINAE)
    template <class Param2>
    typename std::enable_if<! std::is_same<Param, Param2>::value, int>::type
    getParam() const
    { return Parameter<Tail ...>::template getParam<Param2>(); }
};

class Base : public Parameter<A, B>
{ };

class Derived : public Base, public Parameter<C, D>
{ };

int main(int const argc, char const * argv[])
{
  Base base;
  int a = base.getParam<A>(); // ok
  int b = base.getParam<B>(); // ok

  Derived derived;
  int c0 = derived.getParam<C>(); // error: request for member ‘getParam’ is ambiguous
  int c1 = derived.Derived::getParam<C>();  // error: request for member ‘getParam’ is ambiguous
  int c2 = derived.Parameter<C, D>::getParam<C>(); // ok but syntax overly complex, especially if many params

  int a0 = derived.getParam<A>(); // error: request for member ‘getParam’ is ambiguous
  int a1 = derived.Base::getParam<A>(); // ok, could be acceptable if also worked on Derived
  int a2 = derived.Parameter<A, B>::getParam<A>(); // ok but syntax overly complex and confusing

  return 0;
}
```

I realize that several major design changes could address the problem: 1) get rid of the variadic Parameter class template, instead derive from each parameter one at a time 2) make the parameters member variables. But my question is whether I could retain the variadic Parameter class template yet avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Personally, I would write that like this : https://ideone.com/BbLKxb

Comment: @Jarod42 This is not a comment, it's the answer I think!

Comment: @jarod42 slight behaviour change in the single inheritance case: if we we are `Parameter<int,int>` the above gets the first `int`, while your code is ambiguous.  Can be patched if OP cares, but OP might want the error in that case....

Comment: All types given to Parameter are distinct in our application, so no problem there but see my other comment below.

Comment: additional note: ideally, I would like something like a0 and c0 to work, if not, something similar to a1 and c1 would be ok. Something like a2 and c2 is too cumbersome and would drive me away from the variadic template implementation altogether. So it is not necessary for all the mentioned error cases in the original post to pass, just one that avoids having to re-list all the parameter arguments would be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove the `getParam` that doesn't match to avoid ambiguity as follow:  [Demo](http://ideone.com/BbLKxb)

```
template <class ... Params> class Parameter;

template <class Param>
class Parameter<Param> : public Param
{
public:
    //! Get a parameter
    template <class Param2>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Param, Param2>::value, int>::type
    getParam() const
    { return Param::x; }
};

template <class Param, class ... Tail>
class Parameter<Param, Tail ...> : public Parameter<Param>, Parameter<Tail...>
{
public:
    using Parameter<Param>::getParam;
    using Parameter<Tail...>::getParam;
};

class Base : public Parameter<A, B> {};

class Derived : public Base, public Parameter<C, D>
{
public:
    using Base::getParam;
    using Parameter<C, D>::getParam;
};
```

Comment: This is very nice, but `using Parameter<C, D>::getParam;` is annoying for users to write, as they need to keep that statement in sync with the `public Parameter<C, D>` above as they work on fleshing out Derived and they add more parameters to it. Any way to avoid having `Parameter<C, D>` mentioned in two places?

Comment: if `Derived` don't derive of `Base` and just want to extend to `C` and `D`, you may add `template <typename ... Ts> using extend = Parameter<Param, Ts...>;` inside `class Parameter` and then have `class Derived : public Base::extend<C, D>`.

Comment: I ended up using an empty Parameter<...> class that just peels off Parameter<Param> like you did, then I just call regular member functions on those, prefixed by the parameter name (like `derived.Parameter<C>::get()`). So I am accepting your answer but my conclusion is still that the ambiguity between two variadic template inheritance chains is unavoidable.